# How to access UDP from Javascript running in WSH?

Tags: javascript, windows-10, wsh

I am trying to access udp NOT from a browser but running from wscript. I see various solutions that depend on System.Net and System.Net.Sockets but none of them work. They all fail when I try to create the first object (UdpClient).

```
var listenPort = 11000;
listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
```

The error says:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'UdpClient' is undefined

I don't want to be calling external libraries, or install Node.js There surely must be a way to do this, but I can't find it -- or maybe I haven't found the magic search phrase yet.

I would think that WSH would recognize calls from System.Net or System.Net.Sockets, but I guess not. Is there a way to get them included so WSH can access them?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your time...

Michael...

Comment: Show us the code you tried, and the error message indicating why it failed.

Comment: This is as far as I got - trying to declare things:  
  
var listenPort = 11000;  

listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);  
  
The error says:  
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'UdpClient' is undefined

Comment: Have you tried using `WScript.CreateObject(System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient)` or similar?  It's been awhile since I've used WSH, but I believe you need `CreateObject()` to import these packages.

Comment: Nope, didn't help.   
Now it says: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined

Comment: Please show the actual code you just tried... you shouldn't get the exact same error.

Comment: No, it says "System" is undefined now. I edited the reply but I guess it didn't get updated.

Comment: Put `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient` in quotes.

Comment: With it in quotes, the error message is: "WScript.CreateObject: Could not locate automation class named "System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient"."

Comment: Here is an approximate list, or what you might expect by default to have in your computer, of objects that can and can't be created with `CreateObject()` https://gist.github.com/mrpapercut/37287ff1152369e4a89ef0078905393f.